# Perl regex matching too broadly

Tags: regex, perl

I have a strings taken from Linux mail logs that look something like :

```
May 20 12:19:28 example-03 amavis[1445]: (01445-15) Passed SPAMMY {RelayedTaggedInbound}, [10.4.3.2]:49488 [10.4.3.2] <offers-john=example.com@example.net> -> <john@example.com>, Queue-ID: C00OZs0w9DB, Message-ID: <5ZCfDBMQyiUjOVD78ZFxg5%3D%3D@example.net>, mail_id: aCUpU0wtUaR, Hits: 15.587, size: 21407, queued_as: dgzikuucQ9i, 438 ms
```

The element I need to extract is :

```
<offers-john=example.com@example.net> -> <john@example.com>
```

I want to keep my regex as simple and clear as possible, so I don't want to go into regex for email address formats.  Not least because regexing email formats is a bug-prone process !

I have tried :

```
$row =~ /(<.*> -> <.*>,)/;
```

But, despite the presence of the comma delimiter, that syntax matches all the way to the end of the end of Message-ID with an output such as :

```
<offers-john=example.com@example.net> -> <john@example.com>, Queue-ID: C00OZs0w9DB, Message-ID: <5ZCfDBMQyiUjOVD78ZFxg5%3D%3D@example.net>,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it non-greedy by adding `?` to your regex :

```
(<.*?> -> <.*?>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uO1gT9/1)

Comment: Awesome, thanks !  Just need to wait 7 minutes and 30 seconds until I can accept your answer.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

By default the quantifier `*` is greedy. It matches as much as it can, you need to make it lazy (a.k.a. non-greedy) by adding a `?` after it. Here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/hU1gC4/1).

Comment: It's *non-greedy*, not *lazy*

Comment: @Borodin I have heard both terminologies being used, however, I will add the alternative to the answer for completeness' sake.

Comment: *lazy evaluation* refers to something else entirely, and is best not used as a synonym for *non-greedy* as well. The Perl documentation uses the latter throughout

Comment: I am aware that *lazy evaluation* is something else. The Perl documentation may use `non-greedy` throughout, but I have seen enough other documentation (for example the .NET documentation on RegEx) that refers to it as lazy to justify including both terms to make it more accessible to a large user base, seeing as the question does not rely on Perl's specific implementation. The question as to which is more appropriate remains a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

That is much more robustly written without the non-greedy option, and it is clearer if insignificant whitespace is added with the help of the `/x` modifier. Like so

```
$row =~ / ( <[^<>]*> \s* -> \s* <[^<>]*> ) /x;
```

Comment: You learn a new thing every day ..... the x modifier in my case ! ;-)   (Your regex suggestion is very interesting in its own rights too, of course !). Thanks.